# C# Handle file errors

Tags: c#, error-handling, file-io

I am trying to open a file, and I would like to return e.g. X if the filepath does not exist, Y if the file can't be opened, and Z if it was successful.

However, I can't understand how I can check for the "file can't be opened" error and I am not sure my try-catch is correct so far. I would also like to add another statement to check if the file is already open.

```
public int Opener(string fileName)
    { 
    string text = "";
        
        try
        {
            text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            return "Something to Return";
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return "Something to Return";
        }
```

Comment: The function is declared to return an `int`, so you need a number there, like -1, 0, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check the cases you described:

```
try
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    //Z: reading was successful
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is IOException)
    {
        //Y: file is already being read
    }
    else if (ex.InnerException is FileNotFoundException)
    {
        //X: file does not exist
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. But how can I check if the file could not be opened for some reason?

Comment: That would count as **Y**. An `IOException` is caused if the file is already being accessed by another process and therefore can't be opened by your program. It doesn't matter whether the process accessing the file is your program itself or another process.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Do you know if I can use I0Exception to check if the file is already open? And if that's the case, how can I return a different value then? So, return X if file cannot be opened and J if the file is already open.

Comment: Do you mean already open by your program or already open in general?

Comment: Ideally both, but in this case, I would be more interested if the file was already open in general.

Comment: As for your program you could implement a global variable and change it before and after you read the file. But I'm not sure if you can check if the file is open in general. You would have to look that up yourself :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225734/discussion-between-user3755632-and-ottxr).

Answer (score 0):

The function is declared to return an `int`, so you need a number there, like -1, 0, or 1. If you want to return a text error message, change the function return type to `string`.

Comment: I did not want to return a string. It was just to describe the problem.

Comment: If you want to use text or language to describe the problem, you have a string!